# Adding custom application claim for gender

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-ad-b2c

Is it possible to add a custom application claim in azure ad b2c  to determine the user's gender?
i.e. restrict the answer to two choices rather than a string entry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. See the image below, which is an example using built-in policies.

[image]

The same can be done using custom policies.